# Dart using * for making some methods instead definition itself

Tags: flutter, dart, extension-methods

you suppose i have this extension:

```
extension MyWidget on Widget {
  Widget p(double padding) => Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding), child: this);
  Widget p0(double padding) => Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, child: this);
  Widget p1(double padding) => Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(1), child: this);
  Widget p2(double padding) => Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(2), child: this);
  Widget p3(double padding) => Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(3), child: this);
  Widget p4(double padding) => Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(4), child: this);
  Widget p5(double padding) => Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5), child: this);
  Widget p6(double padding) => Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(6), child: this);
  Widget p7(double padding) => Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7), child: this);
  Widget p8(double padding) => Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8), child: this);
  Widget p9(double padding) => Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(9), child: this);
  Widget p10(double padding) => Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), child: this);

  Widget center() => Center(child: this);
}
```

how can i have this sample method instead of all definitions?

```
/* Center().p2 */
/* Center().p8 */
extension MyWidget on Widget {
  Widget p(double padding) => Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding), child: this);
  Widget p*() => Padding(padding: *, child: this);

  Widget center() => Center(child: this);
}
```

i know, i can make this below extension, but i want to know this implementation can be define in dart or not

```
/* Center().p(2) */
extension MyWidget on Widget {
  Widget p(double padding) => Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding), child: this);

  Widget center() => Center(child: this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that syntax or something like it where you're creating dynamic signatures is not possible.

If you're looking to create a variety of signatures for similar functionality, code generation is typically the tool you'll want to look into however for what you want in this case I doubt it's what you're looking for.